Sounddevice simultaneous audio playback auto gain problem
I'm using a Raspberry Pi along with a HiFiBerry DAC + ADC PRO to generate and transmit white noise, and then I'm capturing and reading it back in using a loopback configuration. I use the Sounddevice library playrec to prevent latency, the problem I have is when I send a signal it auto scales it to a value between 0-1. I think the problem is with the datatype only allowing [-1,1] but I have set the dtype to int32 so I don't get why this is not solved. Any way other than to manually scale my data?
Below is my main file:
import Audio_Utils_Sound as audio
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This program is made to test the frequency spectre of a device

# Settings
sample_rate = 44100  # Sample rate for audio playback
duration = 3  # Duration of each test signal in seconds
amplitude = 1  # Amplitude of test signal
channels = 1  # 1 = mono, 2 = stereo
device = 0  # You can specify the ID or the name
dtype = np.int32  # Select the bit depth: np.int8, np.int16, np.int32(24bit doesn't exist so use np.int32)
num_bins = 512

audio.device_setup(channels, sample_rate, device)

num_samples = int(duration * sample_rate)
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(num_samples, sample_rate)
noise = np.random.randn(num_samples)

recorded = audio.write_and_record(noise, sample_rate, channels, dtype)  # Record signal from device
print(max(noise))
print(max(recorded))

# Calculate FFT and decibels of input
amplitude_db_input, freqs_input = audio.fft(noise, sample_rate, duration)
amplitude_db_output, freqs_output = audio.fft(recorded, sample_rate, duration)
amplitude_db_output_gain, freqs_output_gain = audio.fft_gain(noise, recorded, sample_rate, duration)

# Plot frequency response graphs
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

plt.subplot(2, 2, 1)
plt.plot(freqs_input, amplitude_db_input, linestyle='-')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude (dB)')
plt.title('Input Noise')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 2)
plt.plot(freqs_output, amplitude_db_output, linestyle='-')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude (dB)')
plt.title('Frequency Response')
plt.grid(True)

plt.subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(freqs_output_gain, amplitude_db_output_gain, linestyle='-')
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Gain (dB)')
plt.title('Frequency Response')
plt.grid(True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

`
Below is my def file:
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd

def fft(signal, sample_rate, duration):
    num_samples = int(duration * sample_rate)
    
    fft_output = np.fft.fft(signal)
    amplitude_output = abs(fft_output)
    amplitude_db_output = 20 * np.log10(amplitude_output)          
    freqs_output = np.fft.fftfreq(num_samples, sample_rate) # Using np.fft.fftfreq negative frequency's are also created, so we filter this out
    return amplitude_db_output[freqs_output >= 0], freqs_output[freqs_output >= 0]

def fft_gain(output_signal, input_signal, sample_rate, duration):
    num_samples = int(duration * sample_rate)
    
    fft_output = np.fft.fft(output_signal)
    amplitude_output = np.abs(fft_output)
    
    fft_input = np.fft.fft(input_signal)
    amplitude_input = np.abs(fft_input)
    
    gain_db_output = 20 * np.log10(amplitude_input / amplitude_output)
    
    freqs_output = np.fft.fftfreq(num_samples, sample_rate) # Using np.fft.fftfreq negative frequency's are also created, so we filter this out
    
    return gain_db_output[freqs_output >= 0], freqs_output[freqs_output >= 0]

def write_and_record(data, sample_rate, channels, dtype):
    # Play audio and record simultaneously
    frames = sd.playrec(data, samplerate=sample_rate, channels=channels, blocking=True)
    sd.wait()
    return frames[:, 0]     # Returns(frames, channels)

def device_setup(channels, sample_rate, device):
    sd.default.channels = channels
    sd.default.samplerate = sample_rate
    sd.default.device = device
    print('Devices:\n' + str(sd.query_devices()) + '\n')  # print available devices
    # print('Host APIs:\n' + str(sd.query_hostapis())+ '\n')     # print available host APIs
    print('Input:\n' + str(sd.check_input_settings()) + '\n')  # print available devices
    print('Output:\n' + str(sd.check_output_settings()) + '\n\n')  # print available devices


I thought it was the HiFiBerry first but using PyAudio i don't have this scaling problem. When I send a signal with a max value of 4.52 i still get a max value of 0.9999 and I need to calculate the gain so I want to disable this auto gain scale this library introduces. I haven't found anything about this in the Sounddevice documentation, has anyone else had this problem?

This was not a software problem as first thought but rather just the voltage output limitations of the HiFiBerry with a value of 1 corresponding to a voltage of around 2V which is the maximum voltage the module can supply.
